# show specific viewcontroller only in landscape, but support iPad multitasking features

Tags: iphone, ipad, uinavigationcontroller, screen-orientation, multitasking

I´m developing an application for iPad & iPhone.
The App is supporting on iPad all Orientations, because of `Multitaskingfeatures`.
On iPhone my App is supporting only Portrait.

For one Specific ViewController I want on both devices to support only `Landscape`.
On the iPhone was using following solution:

I disabled all orientations in .plist and worked with two `Navigationcontroller`.
One for landscape and one for Portrait.

pushing my VC for Landscape:

```
LandscapeNavigationController *navController = [[LandscapeNavigationController alloc] init];
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController = navController;
    [navController pushViewController:[Logic sharedInstance].myLandscapeViewController animated:YES];
```

Code in my NavigationController:

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {

    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return YES;
}
```

My Problem is that I cant handle the orientation on iPad in code because I have to enable all `Orientations` in .plist to support `Multitasking`.
So the delegatemethods `supportedInterfaceOrientations` in my `Navigationcontroller` wont be called.

Has anybody an idea to support `multitasking` on iPad AND allow one specific `ViewController` only one `supportetInterfaceOrientation`?